# Why an HSM generated key component has parity error?

Tags: cryptography, hsm

Using Thales HSM, the following commands were executed:

1. Generate 2 ZMK components using A2 command:

A20002U;[print fields]

Components are successfully generated and printed, in A3 response we have the encrypted component:

A300[component][CV]

2. Form a key from encrypted components:

A42000U[1st component][2nd component]

Key is successfully formed:

A500[key][CV]

3. Calculate check value of encrypted component:

BUFF1[1st component];000;001

Then we get parity error:

BV10 (Source key parity error)

How is it possible? Is "BU" command not appropriate for obtaining component check value?

Answer (score 1):

Try to check the BU key type.
The key type should be 100 instead of 000

```
BUFF1[1st component];100;001
```

Comment: For A4 command, the number of components should be from 2 to 9.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: The result is the same (key parity error). According to manual, code 100 is used in legacy commands only. 
Finally we ended up with forming a dummy key from 3 identical components using A4 command.